# CImage and stretchblt

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

```
void InitImg(CImage&img)
{
//init the image
}

void DisplayImg(CImage&img)
{
  ///something
  img.StretchBlt(100,100,100,100);
  ///something else 
}
```

I have got an runtime error at  stretchblt (m_hBitmap!=hBitmap)
Debug information shows the img input into the DisplayImg is valid.

Thank you,

Markus

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded, created to attached the `CImage` object, hence the assertion. 
Load the image using [CImage::Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf4bytf8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method, for example.